# Installing Pi-Hole along with Outline ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, vpn

So I am new to ubuntu 18.04, and I want to install Pi-Hole with Outline (a VPN service), but I cant find any tut on how to do it, neither understand how to do it.

So if anyone knows please tell me how